# Working principle behind the recorder in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

The Selenium IDE is able to get information about the recorded controls by subscribing to the events raised by the Firefox browser. This way it is able to write handlers for the subscribed events. Is this correct? Or is it a totally different approach? Could you help us in improving our understanding about this recorder functionality of Selenium IDE?

Comment: Selenium is open source with masses of documentation. You could just read the code etc to find out how it works.

Comment: We do have the source code for it and did reach till the point where the JavaScript function was getting an event object from Firefox which is unwrapped and used. We weren't able to trace it further from there. This is the point we thought that in the Firefox code there must be a registered Selenium listener which is allowed to listen to Firefox browser events. We weren't able to find specific information among the documentation and thus resorted to ask the community for some hints.

Comment: Update: The code we stopped at is at the following location in the Selenium sources : selenium-master\selenium-master\ide\main\src\content\locatorBuilders.js and reads: LocatorBuilders.prototype.buildAll = function(el) {
  var e = core.firefox.unwrap(el);

Comment: If you are not able to trace how existing system works, by definition you do not have skills (yet) to build something smarter on top of that system. IOW: your project is too ambitious for your current skill level. Start with fixing some bugs in Se IDE, ask for help (on their forum) to understand how it works.

Comment: @PeterMasiar, where did the OP wrote he/she wants to build something smarter on top of that system?

Comment: As this question is put on hold I have raised a very specific question in Stack overflow. This is the link to it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260283/addeventlistener-handler-function-not-returning-all-attributes-of-the-event-obje